# I don't get the nausea effect anymore

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm playing on v1.14. It's weird, I don't get the nausea effect anymore, I've tried restarting the game and removing the texture packs that were on. Does anyone know a fix?

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWOIG.jpg)

I was using this command:

```
/execute at @a[distance=..30] as @a[distance=..30] if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:blue_stained_glass_pane run effect give @a minecraft:nausea 3 10 true
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us a little more to go on then that.  What are you doing that you expect to trigger the nausea effect?  Presumably it's a command, since you've included that tag, and if so, what is the command you're using?  Please fully explain your question here, and don't assume that people will watch the video in order to figure out what you mean.

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to Arqade! If you can give us specific instructions here in the question what you're doing to trigger nausea, the community will be much more likely to help. As it stands, it is very difficult to answer your question with the information provided.

Comment: `/execute at @a[distance=..30] as @a[distance=..30] if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:blue_stained_glass_pane run effect give @a minecraft:nausea 3 10 true`
sorry for not linking the command

Comment: Fixed the problem! sorry!

Answer (score 0):

To fix it all you need to do is remove the word minecraft from the command you NEVER use minecraft: for an effect or it won't work, if on bedrock edition type ot out in the chat and then see what the problem is that way, if on java edition then it should show you where there is a problem by being red where the problem starts and to the end

Comment: No that wasn't what fixed the problem. I set it at "effect give @a minecraft:nausea 3 10 true" I needed to make it "effect give @a minecraft:nausea 4 10 true"

Comment: Ok.............